# SVG: Valid applying inline filter="url(....)" on <use> element?

Tags: html, svg-filters

I'm currently using an inline system of SVG's with definitions at the top of the doc, and afterwards showing the icons as so:

```
<svg>
  <use href="#icon" filter="url(#myFilter)"></use>
</svg>
```

However, to enable using filters (such as drop-shadow) in Internet Explorer 10-11 I'm currently applying an inline `filter="url(....)"` to the `<use>` element - and it works as a charm so far.

However I'm not quite sure whether this is a valid method?

Apparently applying the inline `filter="url(...)"` to the `<svg>` element using this method **doesn't** apply the filter correctly in IE10-11.

Code that doesn't work in IE10+

```
<svg filter="url(#myFilter)">
  <use href="#icon"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you applying filter to the SVG element or the USE element - it's not clear in your question. Both cases should work, but please post a minimal, complete test case that doesn't work in IE 10+

Comment: @Michael thank you for the answer and pointing Out that I hadnt made it clear - it's naturally a mistake and I've updated the code example - an example for IE 10-11 Will follow